# triming extension from filename in Excel

Tags: excel, trim

I have this formula. This works great but fails when there are 5 characters including the dot.

For example,

abcdefgh.pdf   =TRIM(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4))  gives me abcdefgh
xyz.xlsx  =TRIM(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-4)) gives me xyz.

Is there a formula that looks for the last dot and trims everything after the last dot?

Comment: yes, you can use `Find`: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-excels-find-and-mid-to-extract-a-substring-when-you-dont-know-the-start-point/1033368

Comment: Just a precaution but using the `TRIM` function in here, unless it is your intent to remove any leading/trailing spaces in the filename after you've removed the extension, which might not be desired.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this formula to get rid of the last dot and everything after

`=LEFT(A1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(".",A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))))-1)`

If there's only ever one dot as per your examples then you only need

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)`

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked in first try.

Answer (score 0):

This formula works well

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

It replaces each period with 100 spaces and then returns the right 100 characters and trims it.  You can also replace "." with "\" to get the filename.

[Credit to NBVC at excelforum.com](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/833633-how-to-extract-filename-from-path-filename.html)

Answer (score 0):

Could try below formula.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"."& RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))),"")
```

This works for file extensions with 2 to 7 character file extensions with full paths and namespaces notation in filename.

you could also use

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))))
```

to find the extension of the file.