# Excel VBA formula: extract file extension from filepath?

Tags: excel, vba

Given an excel column containing filepaths, what excel formula returns only the file extension?

`src\main\java\com\something\proj\UI.java` --> `java`
`src\main\java\com\something\proj\Server.scala` --> `scala`
`src\main\java\com\something\proj\include.h\someinclude.hpp` --> `hpp`

Note 1: this formula works great for filepaths with only a single period, but not for case 3:
`=IF(A1="","",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)))`

Note 2: I understand that these filepaths are Windows-specific, I don't need a cross-platform solution.

Related: [triming extension from filename in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063463/triming-extension-from-filename-in-excel) and [How to extract file name from path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743328/how-to-extract-file-name-from-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find everything after the last `.`:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","{{{",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'm trying to understand how this works - can you explain the approach?

Comment: @user3633993 first it counts the number of `.` and replaces the last `.` with `{{{`.  Then it finds that `{{{` and splits the text string on it.

Comment: It might be safer to use a disallowed character like `*` to split on.  It's a corner case, but `{{{.foo` is a valid file name.

Answer (score 3):

With data in **A1**, use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(".",999)),999),".","")
```

[image]

From:

[Jim Cone's old post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/06FiNc0fDwE)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Trying to understand the approach - can you explain why this works?

Comment: @BradWehrwein  It works because it separates any characters after the last period away from all other characters by 999 dots, or whatever number you choose. You can then select the rightmost 999 characters knowing that you are selecting nothing but your extension characters and a bunch of periods. Substitute out the periods and you're set to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice long answer. :-)

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

A neat trick I sometimes use for string parsing in general is to leverage the `FilterXML()` function (Excel 2013 and later). The basic strategy is to use `Substitute()` to format your string in a way that it is parsed across elements in an xml string, and then you can use [xpath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) syntax to conveniently navigate your parsed elements. Using this strategy, getting an extension would look like this...

```
=FILTERXML("<A><p>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","</p><p>.")&"</p></A>","//p[last()]")
```

If you're not familiar with xml, this can seem intimidating, but if you can grasp what's going on, I find it to be cleaner, more flexible, and easier to remember than the alternative approaches using len(), substitute(), etc. One reason why it's nicer is because there's only one cell reference.

**Illegal Characters**

There are two characters that are allowed in paths but not in xml: `&` and `'`

The equation above will work if these characters are not present, otherwise, they will need to be handled something like this...

`=FILTERXML("<A><p>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J8,"'",""),"&",""),".","</p><p>.")&"</p></A>","//p[last()]")`

**Example**

Suppose we have a nasty file path like this:

C:\Folder1\Folder2\(ugly characters !@#$%^()_+={};;,`)\two.dots.LongExt

1.) The `Substitution()` portion will convert it to an xml string like this...

```
<A>
    <p>
        C:\Folder1\Folder2\(ugly characters !@#$%^()_+={};;,`)\two
    </p>
    <p>
        .dots
    </p>
    <p>
        .txt
    </p>
</A>
```

2.) Once formatted like this, it's trivial to pick out the last `p` element using the xpath syntax `//p[last()]`.